# Trace facebook user IP address. Is it even possible?

Tags: facebook, websocket

AS i know Facebook chat is running on XMPP protocol. It is decentralised, but not P2P. It is similar to email - there is no central server, but lots of domain servers talking to each other and taking care of their clients. I am think about that is it possible to get user IP address who chat with us with coding or programming if so then how?

Comment: Doesn't matter if Facebook is running XMPP or not. You can't get a users IP address. If you could that would be a security bug and you should report it at https://www.facebook.com/whitehat and we will fix it really really quickly

Comment: okay it is not limited to facebook i just give example let consider i am here chatting with you can i find your IP address and exact location

Comment: I would claim it is a security bug at StackOverflow if you can.

Comment: yeah that might b but i wanna learn

Comment: cross-posted: https://askubuntu.com/q/819273/175814

Comment: @DavidFoerster two are different communities and ASk ubuntu  work on Command that;s why i put it there also

Comment: It is impossible coz we are connected through server and our ip will go to server instead user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, its not possible.

[RFC 6120: Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP): Core](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120) states the following in [Section 13.10: Information Leaks](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-13.10):

```
13.10.1.  IP Addresses
   A client's IP address and method of access MUST NOT be made public by
   a server (e.g., as typically occurs in [IRC]).
```

If a client requests its own IP address, that policy is not violated.  However, a server MUST NOT return the IP address of another client (e.g., if a connected client sends a `SIC` request to the bare JID of another user); instead, it MUST return a [`forbidden`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-8.3.3.4) error.

Comment: when we find connection with NETSTAT command isit possible to find particular user

Comment: only connection to FB

Comment: how can you explore?

Comment: tcpdump or wireshark

Comment: i think that is used for analysis of your network traffic

Comment: yes, all connections from vmWare host... i cannot run it from their server

Comment: okay as you chat with me right now isit possible to get your ip address or find your exact location ?? if so then how

Comment: yes, send me link to picture on your server, and in .htaccess rewrite to php file, log $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to file and show me pic

Comment: thats something called phishing if i am right? i wanna find it without user come to know that i am tracking them

Comment: user known only pic on server like this - http://some_server/picture.jpg :)

Comment: everything else - at your discretion

Answer (score -1):

No you can't. Only way that would be possible, is by doing som serious social engineering and phising...